What's the minimum number of moves to solve this Water Sort puzzle?
These are the rules of the game Water Sort:

You start with several flasks containing layers of differently-colored liquids, with just enough of each color to completely fill one flask.
Your goal is to get each color of liquid entirely within a single flask.
A move consists of pouring the top layer of liquid from one flask to another, as follows:

Either the source flask and the destination flask must have the same color of liquid as their top layers, or the destination flask must be empty.
Pouring continues until either the destination flask is full, or the entire top layer of the source flask has been poured.




For example, the above game can be solved in 5 moves, as follows: 1 to 3, 5 to 3, 2 to 1, 5 to 2, and 5 to 1.
The puzzle: how many moves does it take to solve the below game? A valid answer will include both a list of N moves that solve it, plus a proof that it can't be solved in N-1 or fewer moves.

You can try solving either of these interactively at https://watersort.org/menu by changing "Level generation" to "Old", and "Current level" to 3 for the example game, and 387 for the puzzle game.
Hint:

 It's trivial to solve in 24 moves, and it's trivial to prove that it can't be solved in 22 or fewer moves, so you need to figure out whether or not it can be solved in 23 moves.


PS: Some users seem to be confused about the water levels. According to the source code of the game page: 

Or simplified by $8$:

Each flask can hold $40$ units of liquid (if simplified by $8$). Here's the text format (from top to bottom):
Flask 1:

- Light green (7 units of volume)
- Teal (33)

Flask 2:

- Teal (7)
- Orange (11)
- Dark teal (21)

Flask 3:

- Light brown (7)
- Light blue (8)
- Dark purple (25)

Flask 4:

- Pink (9)
- Red (9)
- Light blue (22)

Flask 5:

- Pink (7)
- Red (10)
- Purple (17)

Flask 6:

- Light brown (6)
- Purple (17)
- Dark purple (6)
- Orange (11)

Flask 7:

- Red (7)
- Light green (14)
- Orange (12)
- Red (7)

Flask 8:

- Pink (8)
- Light blue (10)
- Light green (19)

Flask 9:

- Pink (6)
- Red (7)
- Light brown (27)

Flask 10:

- Pink (10)

Flask 11:

- Purple (6)
- Dark purple (9)
- Orange (6)
- Dark teal (19)

Flask 12:

Empty


Unfortunately, at https://watersort.org/menu  I do not see an option to set 387 for the puzzle game.

Can you provide the liquid levels/quantities and colours as text, and the capacity of the flasks? From the current answer, it looks like it's impossible to know what moves are legal using just the images posted here.

PS: Some users seem to be confused about the water levels. Found out this upon inspecting the source:

Or simplified by $8$:

We can easily prove that it takes a least $23$ moves:

 There are $33$ chunks of different liquids in total, and we have to reduce them to $10$ because there are $10$ different colors.

$23$ moves aren't enough because:

 Solving it in only $23$ moves requires not pouring any into an empty vial. Eventually:  Teal liquid: All of it would end up in vial $1$.  Dark purple: Vial $3$.  Light blue: Vial $4$.  Purple: Vial $5$.  Orange: Vial $6$  Red: Vial $7$.  Green: Vial $8$.  Brown: Vial $9$.  Isolating the pink liquid is trivial, resulting in this configuration:    The next move involves pouring some red liquid into Vial $4$ or $5$.  For the purple liquid to be isolated, the red one at the top of Vial $5$ must be poured somewhere else, but it can't be fully gotten rid of with one move until Vial $7$ is down to the red liquid at the bottom.  For Vial $7$ to be down to the red liquid, the green in it must have been poured into Vial $8$ because no other vial can hold it.  Even before that, the light blue liquid at the top of Vial $8$ must have been poured into Vial $4$, because no other vial can hold it. To expose the bottom of Vial $4$, the red at the top must have been poured into Vial $5$ in advance, but it can't be done if any red liquid is touched before. So we do this and get the trivial stuff done:    We end up needing an empty vial, so it's impossible.

An example that takes $24$ moves:

 - First, isolate the pink in $4$ moves:    - Then dump the red liquid at the top of $4$ vials into the empty vial:    - Then isolate the brown and light blue liquids in the next $4$ moves ($2$ for each):    - Later, do the same for the purple, light green and dark purple liquids in the next $6$ moves ($2$ for each):    - Now you can complete it:  $1$ move for teal  $3$ for orange  $1$ more for red  $1$ for dark teal.


It's not obvious (starting from your final picture) why you can't pour red 7->9, green 8->9, orange 7->2, red 5->7, red 9->7 etc.

You can't get all the red into one vial without using an empty one. No other vial can hold what's at the top of 5, and 7->9 is impossible because the latter can't hold enough (I tried).

Why is red 7->9 impossible? (It looks like it should easily fit.) Are there some constraints in the game that aren't given in the question?

And green 8->9 is a typo. I meant green 7->8.

I actually tried it when I played the game at the site. Very little red stays in 7.

For completeness, you should give an example sequence showing that filling an empty vital with red liquid is sufficient to solve the puzzle.

Solutions in 24 moves were called trivial by OP, but still.

Simpler way to show the minimum: Since all the colors must be separated, there must be at least one move for each layer that is not touching the bottom. There are 22 such layers, count them. But 22 moves cannot be enough, because two colors cannot be unified (put in a single flask) without an additional move:

Two vials (2nd and 11th) have a dark green layer at the bottom. At least one of them must be moved.
Vial 7 has two red layers. After all layers except the red bottom have been poured out (see above), the two reds are in separate vials and must be unified: either the bottom red layer must be poured out as well, or what used to be the top red layer must be poured back into vial 7. Either way, at least one extra move is needed.

So that makes a minimum of 24 moves. I won't copy the "trivial" 24-move solution, you can read it in @Nautilus's answer (or better yet, try it out and follow your heart :-) )

Your second point is not valid. Pouring the top red out of flask 7 does not require an extra move, if it is poured on to another red, so the "return" pour is the one already counted for the other red volume. The fact that this cannot be done is the core of Nautilus' argument

@fljx, pouring out the top red is not the extra move. As you say, it has been counted already. But once you pour it out, you have red in two different places and you need at least one additional move to unify them. You must either pour out the bottom red layer as well, or pour the top red layer back in. Do you see it now? Vial sizes etc. etc. etc. don't need to come into it.

No. There are five separate chunks of red, so they can be combined in four pours, as long as every pour of red is onto another red. The fact that one red starts above another doesn't change that number or add an extra move. The only thing that prevents a 23-move solution is the flask sizes.

I appreciate you are counting things differently, but you should be looking at my argument more carefully instead of offering an alternative. There's no way to put these red layers in one place without either moving all five (including the one at the bottom), or moving one twice. That's what I've been saying.

But if you're sure that the flask sizes are  the only thing preventing a shorter solution, please demonstrate: Assume the flasks are arbitrarily tall and show us how it's done with 23 moves. I don't see how I could be mistaken, but this will prove that I am.

The following sequence (ignoring flask sizes) puts all the red together in flask 7, with only four pours of red (the minimum). There is no extra red pour required:
Pink 4->10, Pink 5->10, Pink 8->10, Pink 9->10, Red 4->5, Red 7->9, Cyan 8->4, Green 1->8, Green 7->8, Teal 2->1, Orange 7->2, Red 5->7, Red 9->7

And for completeness, everything else is sorted out by:
Light Brown 3->9, Light Brown 6->9,
Cyan 3->4,
Purple 6->5, Purple 11->5,
Dark purple 6->3, Dark purple 11->3,
Orange 2->6, Orange 11->6,
Dark Teal 11->2.  23 pours in total.

Thank you! Ok, you are right and I see what I had overlooked: The bottom red layer can be moved before some of the other red layers, avoiding an extra move when bringing it back. Appreciate your demonstration!

(i'll edit my answer asap.)
